Fundamental set for families of abelian varieties
I'm considering the universal family of principally polarized g-dimensional abelian varieties with level N-structure. Let's briefly recall the usual construction as a quotient of $\mathbb{C}^g \times \mathbb{H}_g$, where $\mathbb{H}_g$ denotes the Siegel upper half space. Denote by $\textrm{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$ the symplectic group with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ and define
$$
\Gamma(N):=\textrm{ker}[\textrm{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z}) \to \textrm{Sp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb Z)].
$$
The semidirect product $\mathbb Z^{2g} \rtimes \Gamma(N)$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{C}^g \times \mathbb{H}_g$ and the quotient is the universal family that we mentioned above.
I have two questions:
1. What is a fundamental domain $\mathcal F$ of this last action?
Maybe I found an answer in a paper of Z. Gao (see "A special point problem of André-Pink-Zannier in the universal family of Abelian varieties" - Theorem 2.1 (3)). I'm not sure that I'm interpreting correctly what he means in the language of Shimura varieties, but I think he is saying that the fundamental domain can be constructed as follows. Let $\mathcal F_N$ be a fundamental domain for the action of $\Gamma(N)$ on $\mathbb H_g$ and let $F_\tau$ be the usual fundamental domain of the action of the lattice $\Lambda_\tau:=\mathbb Z^{2g} + \tau \mathbb Z^{2g}$ on $\mathbb C^g$, i.e.
$$
F_\tau:=\{z = x + \tau y : x,y \in\mathbb R^g \textrm{ and } 0\le |x_i|, |y_i| < 1 \textrm{ for each } i=1, \ldots, g\}.
$$
Therefore the fundamental domain $\mathcal F$ could be defined as
$$
\mathcal F:= \bigcup_{\tau \in \mathcal F_N} (N\cdot F_\tau) \times \{\tau\}.
$$
Why we need to multiply the fundamental domain $F_\tau$ by $N$?
2. Why the corresponding uniformization map can be constructed by means of theta functions?
I read in a paper that the uniformization map $\mathbb C^g \times \mathbb H_g \to \mathbb C^g \times \mathbb H_g/\mathbb Z^{2g} \rtimes \Gamma(N)$ can be expressed in terms of theta functions but I've not found references for it. May someone explain better to me why this is possible or give a reference?
Thank you in advance.
